# Gnuplot: cut circles outside range

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file with 3 columns. The first column specifies a x coordinate, 2nd column is a y coordinate and 3rd column is a radius. Then, I plot my file using

```
plot 'fg.txt' u 1:2:3 w circles
```

which gives a result as follows:

[image]

note that the pink circles are actually from my file. However, I am only interested in the part that is inside the blue circle (which I added manually with `set object`). So how can I cut off everything that is outside the blue circle? Additionally, I would like to plot that on a polar coordinate system.

Comment: I would try to adapt this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/42845332/7010554. For the blue circle, one could try to use a file or a parametric function instead of the circle object.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to make a parametric plot and read a variable from a datafile? because in this case I could plot the parametric function x = x0 + r cos t and y = y0 + r sin t where the variables x0, y0 and r must be read from the data file and t goes from 0 to 2*pi.